# Google Maps. Draw outline based on city

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have been trying to google this but with no luck. 
Has anyone stumbled across some logics/functions to draw a nice area around a city automaticly?

Like the image below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Geo Boundary data. They hold the long/lat to create polygons around the desired city/state/area or whatever area you are looking for.
The [U.S. Census Bureau Geography](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-cart-boundary.html) has downloadable files that provide this type of data for the U.S. [World Countries - GIS Data](https://wagda.lib.washington.edu/data/geography/world/) has other areas world wide.

Comment: The US Census Bureau only has data for the US.

Answer (score 0):

OSM has polygon data for level 2 administrative units (country -> prefecture -> county) as well, you can get them via either overpass (ttp://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter) or nominatim (https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search) interface. I've written a small tool to do so (https://github.com/tibetty/QueryGeoBoundary), you can find more how-to-do details from my source. After you have such data in hand, it will be easy to draw such polygons upon map 'coz most tools have api in place.